# I can create a prototype page and then change it with php?

Tags: php, html

My idea was to create a prototype of the page, and then change it in php.
Example: I need to create a page for 100 people,
I can create a page for example has all the tags, and then for each person to take information from a structured file(name, surname, age, etc ...) and I edit these tags with php, but without actually changing the "prototype" page?

Comment: You may want to look at using a framework to build templates, if you know php why not check out Laravel.   There is a website called Laracasts that has a tutorial series for beginners, and their documentation is fantastic!

Comment: You could of course do this with raw PHP and not use a framework if you so choose.  I just find the syntax of the raw PHP way really awkward to read, Laravel's blade engine is super clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's entirely possible. In fact, that's what PHP was originally made for, as a template processor for HTML pages (it had since evolved, but still retained that quality).

Worth noting that it's usually considered best practice to not have any sophisticated logic in your template files (no database access, no filesystem, no computation logic, just data and content).